# Transportation on the Mars I Underground

Tags: mars, mining, transport

Mars has dust storms which can affect ground based transportation,consequently, underground transport systems seems a better option than on ground transport.

An [underground loop transport](https://www.boringcompany.com/tunnels) system which is under development for the city of [Chicago](https://www.wired.com/story/elon-musk-boring-company-contract-chicago/) with the main purpose to avoid traffic but can it be used for transportation on Mars with proper customization?
What issues (different from Earth) need to be addressed to build such a system on Mars?

Comment: This is a really interesting topic, but you are asking too many different questions in one place. There's no limit to the number of questions you can ask. Loop transports, underground tunnels, solar power cars, flying vehicles and "other possibilities" should all be asked as *separate questions*.  Why not choose the most interesting part and focus on it here, and then cut and paste the other topics into new questions. The answers to your first question many give you additional ideas or thoughts that change the way you would want to ask the others. Each will have a different answer.

Comment: Dust storms on Mars are actually very mild. Maximum wind speed during Mars dust storms is about 60 mph, and because the atmosphere on Mars is very thin this equates to about a 7 mph wind on Earth. Dust on Mars is very fine, similar to particles in wildfire smoke on Earth. Even in major dust storms it accumulates less than 0.1 millimeter on the ground. As described in the answer that you received, to build underground tunnels is very difficult. It would be solving a problem that doesn't really exist. Although there could be other reasons to build underground transportation.

Comment: I don't want to come down too hard on a new user, but I think we should have a regex that scans questions for "need to be addressed" and pops up a warning about being too broad.

Comment: All too speculative/hypothetical for definitive answers and I am disappointingly doubtful any kind of colony - as opposed to a base - is achievable without SF grade, ie non-existent technologies and much advanced Earthly capabilities. Dust storms are one of the problems but they are seasonal, ie periods of likelihood are predictable but I think dust and the problems it causes will be all the time.

Answer (score 5):

The abandoned Chicago project you ask about was developed by the [Boring Company](https://www.boringcompany.com/tunnels). Such a project used a tunnel boring machine to excavate a tunnel which is then concrete lined for stability and then furnished for a planned transportation system: rail, road, etc. It's similar to how many other tunnels are established on Earth. Such a tunnel system could be established on Mars, as you ask.

The main problems with establishing such a tunnel system on Mars are:

- Getting the tunnel boring equipment to the site on Mars. The main
  question here is would the tunnel boring machine and all associated
  equipment be made on Earth and sent to Mars, or would it be made on
  Mars, after having established mines and factories?
- Obtaining geological information along the proposed route of the
  tunnels. This would require prior core drilling to ascertain rock
  types and ground conditions. Getting the equipment to do this faces
  the same problems as getting the tunnel equipment to site on Mars.
- Getting the skilled people on Mars to undertake the project. Such
  people would need to have sufficient experience to solve problems as
  they arise on Mars.
- Obtaining the raw materials on Mars to manufacture an equivalent to
  the concrete tunnel lining panels that will support the tunnel when
  finally excavated. Similarly getting materials for the roadway and
  other tunnel refurbishments, such as lighting, if deemed necessary. This would include getting supplies of electricity needed to develop the project.
- Working in a hostile environment. Earth has a breathable atmosphere,
  comfortable temperatures (generally) and water, particularly for dust
  suppression is usually in plentiful supply. Mars is cold, it's
  atmosphere is very thin and unbreathable, and water supply would be
  problematic. Dust suppression, during tunnel boring, might be able to
  be mitigated using fans and ventilation ducting given there is a weak
  atmosphere on Mars. Dust suppression on the Moon would be more
  problematic because it effectively has not atmosphere. Unless the
  developing tunnels were pressurized with a breathable atmosphere,
  with appropriate air locks, humans working or inspecting the
  operations would need to were a space suit. This would reduce safety
  because of limited movement, vision and hearing. This would require
  the tunneling and tunnel refurbishment processes to be heavily
  automated.

Comment: Cold temperatures may not be much of an issue. Because of the thin atmosphere most heat loss will be due to radiation. Assuming that the workers are wearing pressure suits it would not be much different than current EVA's on ISS during night passes. Although future Mars pressure suits may use elastic pressure garments instead of inflatable, but heating elements could be built in. Also working underground the temperatures might be more mild, but I have no information on that. Future pressure suits may have excellent visibility, mobility, and amplified audio to hear sound in the thin atmosphere.

Comment: @StevePemberton: cold temperature will also affect equipment: brittleness, temperature gradients & thermal stresses.

Comment: Good points. Your answers can be applied to pretty much any infrastructure work on Mars, highlighting the challenges of building a Mars colony, or cities on Mars with over a million people. Not too many details about this are known from SpaceX. In a Q&A in 2016 when it was pointed out that Musk didn't say much about how people will live on Mars, Musk's answer was that the goal of SpaceX is to build the "railroad", then "once that transport system is built then there's a tremendous opportunity for anyone who wants to go to Mars and create something new or build the foundations of a new planet".